# Find the matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

> Find the matrix A that has two rows and two columns and has
>   $$A\pmatrix{1\\ 1}=\pmatrix{2\\ 1}\text{ and }A\pmatrix{-1\\1}=\pmatrix{1\\-1}.$$

**Question:**

How do I write out the corresponding system of linear equations with $4$ equations and $4$ unknowns so I can determine $A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write a system of linear equations, then you can write $$A=\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c&d\end{pmatrix}$$

and then see that $$A\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c&d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}a+b \\ c+d\end{pmatrix}$$

so that gives you the first two equations $a+b=2$ and $c+d=1$.

You do similarly for the other vector and you will have four equations.

---

If you learned linear algebra before, you may also take an alternative approach. Remember that matrices are really just representations of linear operators given a basis. If you do not know what that means, don't worry. You will probably learn that soon.

You can express $\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} = \alpha \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} + \beta\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$

and $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1\end{pmatrix} = \gamma \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} + \delta \begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$

and then you can conclude that in the basis $$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$

the linear operator $\mathcal A$, which in the standard basis is represented by $A$, is represented by a matrix $A' = \begin{pmatrix}\alpha&\beta1 \\ \gamma & \delta\end{pmatrix}$

Then, finding $A$ is just a matter of **changing the basis** for $\mathcal A$, since $A$ is, by definition, the representation of $\mathcal A$ in the standard basis.